# adding extra info to relations

Tags: data-model

I'm setting up CiviCRM for an animal charity organisation. Beside some problems to set up animal master data derived from an individual (e.g. animals usually don't have last names, etc.), I'm stuck with certain events which are related to both an individual and an animal (e.g. adoption or handover):

I wanted to create relations for such events, but I need to add further data to such relations, e.g. for the event "handover" the contract date, date of handover, reason for handover, and other.

Is there a way of storing such data assigned to an event, and assigning this event to both an individual and an animal? Relation doesn't seem to fit such a need ...

Regards

Bernhard

Answer (score 2):

I would make "handover" an action rather than an event. Actions are things like meetings and phone calls, natively include two or more contacts and a timestamp, and you can add action types of your own by going to Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Activity Types. Play around with that and see if it works for you.